# Aspect before call to org.apache.commons.logging.Log.warn

Tags: apache, log4j, aop, aspectj

what I'd like to do, is have an aspect which listens to a call to org.apache.commons.logging.Log.warn and does something after the call.

Is that possible?

I created an aspect like this, but it doesn't ever get called when I do a LOG.warn:

```java
@Pointcut("execution(* org.apache.commons.logging.Log.warn.*.*(..))")
public void warn() {}

@Around("warn()")
public void collect(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
  System.out.println("debug - 1"); // I have a breakpoint here that never gets hit
}
```

Test class:

```java
private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(TestCollectMessagesAspect.class);

public String testCall(String param) {
    LOG.warn("this is a test");
    return param;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical pitfall for AspectJ beginners: You are trying to intercept method `execution()`, but in order to achieve this you need to weave your aspect into the target code, i.e. into Commons Logging in this case. In order to do that you would have to do binary weaving and create a woven version of the 3rd party JAR.

While this is possible, there is a simpler solution, provided you control the calling code and are only interested in warnings created by your own code, not by other 3rd party libs or so. If so, just switch from `execution()` to `call()` pointcuts. This will weave the callers rather than the callee.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. yes, I control the calls to the method, I'm only interested in ones we make.  But, when I try and use it I get an error the spring AOP doesn't support the call joinpoint...

Comment: True. This is documented behaviour. Read the text box named "other pointcut types" on the right hand side of http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/aop.html for reference. Having said that, I suggest you to use full-blown AspectJ which integrates nicely with Spring. Besides, Spring AOP only works with Spring Beans anyway, so even if there was a `call()` pointcut in Spring AOP it would not work for non-Spring libraries like Apache Commons Logging.